# Get Facebook User's real id using App Scoped Id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-apps

I know this question already has been discussed, But I'm here with a different way and a confusion.

**First** : if I do debugging in Graph API Explorer it returns different `app_scoped_user_id` and it return me correct `json` when I run `graph.facebook.com/$app_scoped_user_id` but with my app it generate different App Scoped ID which don't works with above method. Why that happen?

**Second** : I thought to get last redirect url using `CURL` but it returns `http://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=http://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/$app_scoped_user_id` . Now I've two thoughts (may be stupid thoughts),

1. Can I open that app scoped url in a popup window and get that window url after redirection and close the popup?
2. Can I login in Facebook anyhow using `CURL` so that i can get real `user_id`?

I know, app scoped user id can be used. But I want to give it a try.

Comment: No there is no way to get the real user id and that is by design

Comment: Concerning your First question: You're using two different Apps, hence the app-scoped id is different.

Answer (score -1):

**Warning: Facebook old API in use**

There's a way to get it, but you won't like it:

1. get the user to log in to your app via Facebook
2. make a second call to the API using the retrieved access token to get their username
   https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={THE_ACCESS_TOKEN}
3. make a third call to that username without an access token to get their Facebook id
   https://graph.facebook/{USERNAME} <= No access token here!

EDIT: sorry, old API is used here.

Comment: The field `username` has been removed with API 2.0